# struts2 submit form and show result in a new window

Tags: struts2, window, show

struts.xml

```
<action name="run" class="editTrackerAction" method="run">
        <result name="input">/jsp/editTracker.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

editTracker.jsp

```
<s:form method="post" name="saveTracker" id="saveTracker">
<input type="submit" name="executeEntityButtonName"
                id="executeEntityOnTableSubmit" value="Run Entity"  onclick="executeEntityOnTable();">
```

*.js has function

```
function executeEntityOnTable() {

    document.saveTracker.action="run"; 
document.saveTracker.onsubmit=window.open('jsp/thankyou.jsp', 'executeEntityOnTable', 'width=450,height=300,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
document.saveTracker.submit();
```

}

In Page editTracker.jsp, I need to click submit button to show result variable defined in action in Page jsp/thankyou.jsp in a new window, editTracker.jsp page still stay there after submit form as struts.xml configured, but I can't get result in jsp/thankyou.jsp because it is pop up before saveTracker form submit.

Answer (score 2):

You would likely be better off submitting the form via ajax then opening the new window.

If you submit a form with a normal request, the page will update; that's just the way it works. If you mean the form submission reloads the *same* page again, that's fine, but you still need to interact with the server before the new window opens.

Answer (score 0):

try to use your Form something like below and use the following javascript function as well.

```
<form name="myForm" action="myaction.do" method="post" 
              onsubmit="return createTarget(this.target)" target="formtarget">
```

javascript function....

```
function createTarget(t){

           var left = (screen.width/2)-(700/2);
        var top = (screen.height/2)-(550/2);
        window.open("", t,"status = 1,height = 550,width = 700,resizable = 1,left="+left+",top="+top); 

            return true;
        }
```

I've done some formatting for the new window as well.

Regards.